# C# -Converting a list of one class to list of another class with same properties

Tags: c#, asp.net, generics, collections

I am having a method to return a list of class A. But i am storing the List of another class with same properties and need to return this class.

Code:

```
public List<Menu> GetAllMenus()
{
    Menu _menu = null;
    List<Menu> MenuList = new List<Menu>();
    List<Menu2> CacheMenuList=new List<Menu2>();
    //Caching
    string CacheKey = "GetAllMenus";
    ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
    if (cache.Contains(CacheKey))
        CacheMenuList= (List<Menu2>)cache.Get(CacheKey);
    return CacheMenuList
}
```

Both the types Menu and Menu2 have the same properties.
Due to the requirement I need to return it as another list of type Menu2.
In the above code am not not able to return the CacheMenuList since it is of type Menu2. Is there any other way i can do it. I am getting the following error.

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DailyThanthi.Contracts.Menu2>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<DailyThanthi.Contracts.Menu>' DailyThanthi.Repository D:\Prjct\DTNewsRevamp\DailyThanthi.Common\DailyThanthi.Repository\MenuRepository.cs 85  Active

Comment: You will have to cast or convert each object of type `Menu` to `Menu2`. Check out "automapper" as one way, or just write code to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way to do it:

```
CacheMenuList= ((List<Menu>)cache.Get(CacheKey)).Select(
    x => new Menu2 () {
        Property1 = x.Property1,
        Property2 = x.Property2,
        Property3 = x.Property3,
        Property4 = x.Property4
    }
).ToList();
```

You basically create a `Menu2` object for each `Menu` object in `List<Menu>`. You assign each `Menu` property to the corresponding property in `Menu2`.

Comment: I cannot do this because i am making the List<Menu> as null in another function. Due to that am getting the error Value cannot be null. Parameter name: source. so i am trying out whether any way i can do it

Answer (score 3):

I suggest using the excellent library [Automapper](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper) for this, which should be especially easy if the attributes are exactly the same. Here is a minimal working example:

```
Mapper.Initialize(cfg => cfg.CreateMap<Menu, Menu2>());

List<Destination> cacheMenuList = Mapper.Map<List<Menu>, List<Menu2>>(sources);
```

If the properties do not map 1:1 against each other, you have to adjust the configuration when initializing the mapper.

Read more about Automapper in general [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki) and about mapping collections [here](https://github.com/AutoMapper/AutoMapper/wiki/Lists-and-arrays).

Answer (score 1):

How about creating an interface and returning a list of that?

```
public interface IMenu { ... }

public class Menu : IMenu { ... }

public class Menu2 : IMenu { ... }


public List<IMenu> GetAllMenus()
    {
        List<IMenu> result = new List<Menu>();
        //Caching
        string CacheKey = "GetAllMenus";
        ObjectCache cache = MemoryCache.Default;
        if (cache.Contains(CacheKey))
            result= (List<IMenu>)cache.Get(CacheKey);
            return result;
}
```

Or something similar.